# Whether to post in stackoverflow or wordpress.stackexchange.com?

Tags: discussion, wordpress-se

Now there are dedicated stackexchange sites for wordpress, drupal etc. I got a question regarding the wordpress and so I asked it in wordpress.stackexchange.com. But as the audience is less, I didn't get an answer.

But I am sure that I would get a response if posted it on stackoverflow. If I pasted the same question, it will be marked as double posting across the network.

So how can I point the stackoverflow users to the wordpress question and get a response?

Comment: Was the question a programming question? If not, it doesn't belong on Stack Overflow. In any event, "no one uses this site because no one uses it" is a sure way to destroy a site.

Comment: There is of course a difference between audience and audience that can answer your question. Stack overflow is obviously bigger, but the percentage of people who can actually answer your question is tiny.  The situation is reversed on a more specific site